# My JSON data variables are empty

Tags: php, json

I have JSON data being fed in which I have set manually for debugging purposes. I'm trying to get the data to be stored in to their own variables (for later DB storage), however, they are empty.

I have tried 2 different things yet it's still appearing as empty when `echo`'ing them out. Is there a better way of doing this and one that will actually store the data in the required variables?

```
$json = '[{
    "q1":"a",
    "q2":"d"
    }]';

$questions = json_decode($json, true);

$q1 = $questions->q1; //first method of getting the data
$q2 = $questions['q2']; //second attempted method

echo "q1: ".$q1;
echo "q2: ".$q2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the square braces around the json string:

```
$json = '{
  "q1":"a",
  "q2":"d"
}';

$questions = json_decode($json, true);

$q1 = $questions['q1']; //first method of getting the data
$q2 = $questions['q2']; //second attempted method

echo "q1: ".$q1;
echo "q2: ".$q2;
```

Edit: Since you are planning on sending the information over AJAX, say using something like

```
JSON.stringify($('#formId').serializeArray());
```

you may end up with an JSON array, as per your original post.  In that case, you may want to do a for loop, or access the question directly like so:

```
$json = '[{
  "q1":"a",
  "q2":"d"
}]';

$questions = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($questions as $question) {
  $q1 = $question['q1']; //first method of getting the data
  $q2 = $question['q2']; //second attempted method
}

// This would also work:
echo $questions[0]['q1'];
```

Comment: Ah now the second method works :) Thank you @Jonathan. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I like to use an associative array, and then do a json_encode, but it's hard to say what's better without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Edit: here's the PHP article on arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Ok so what I'm trying to do is receive responses to questions (q1-q4 with a-d as response options), then decode and store the values in to the DB (column names q1, q2...).

Comment: Are you receiving responses from the client-side (ex.: via a form), or are you receiving responses from PHP?  I'd say if you're getting a JSON string from a form (ex.: via AJAX), what you're doing is great.

Comment: Yep from an AJAX form. Thanks again!

Comment: OK.  I added a little more information that could prove useful once you get there.  :)